# BigQuery - Illegal Escape Sequence at REGEXP_REPLACE

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm having an issue matching regular expression in BigQuery.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(tc.metadata->>'document_number', '\D', '', 'g') = m.document_number
```

However, BigQuery doesn't seem to like escape sequences for some reason and I get this error that I can't figure out:

```
Syntax error: Illegal escape sequence: \D
```

This code works fine, but BigQuery is unhappy with it and I can't figure out why. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: can you double check your code snippet  - it makes no much sense to me at all - please elaborate

Answer (score 7):

You need to double escape the the character in BigQuery, as the first `/` will be consumed by JavaScript.

Try double escaping, e.g. `\\D` and that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In [1] if you scroll down you can see the escaping sequences of standard SQL and none is `\D`, so as Ben P says, you need to double escape to have the backslash escaping sequence. I assume it's what is missing but if you could elaborate further your question the answer would be indeed more accurate.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string_and_bytes_literals